# BHO , worker thread hangs in COM calls when the main thread waits for it to finish

Tags: multithreading, internet-explorer, deadlock, bho

I have a BHO with a worker thread iterating through the image elements of the document. I use GIT(global interface table ) to marshal and unmarshal the IWebBrowser2 object. When Internet Explorer is closed I set an event(which I check in the worker thread if is signaled) and wait for the thread to finish. The worker thread hangs in a method call on a COM object(not the same call every time) and the process is deadlocked.

Comment: In your BHO thread (not the worker one) *try* to use a waiting function that allows message processing: MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx